# An integer (a string of digits) is $\text{/[0-9][0-9]$\ast$/}$. (Why isn't it just $\text{/[0-9]$\ast$/}$?)

Tags: regular-expressions, natural-language-processing

I am currently studying the textbook [*Speech and Language Processing*, 3rd edition (draft), by Jurafsky and Martin](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/). Chapter **2.1.1 Basic Regular Expression Patterns** says the following:

> The regular expression $\text{/[1234567890]/}$ specifies any single digit. While such classes of characters as digits or letters are important building blocks in expressions, they can get awkward (e.g., it's inconvenient to specify
>
> $$\text{/[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]/}$$
>
> to mean "any capital letter"). In cases where there is a well-defined sequence associated with a set of characters, the brackets can be used with the dash (-) to specify any one character in a range. The pattern $\text{/[2-5]/}$ specifies any one of the characters 2, 3, 4, or 5. The pattern $\text{/[b-g]/}$ specifies one of the characters b, c, d, e, f, or g. Some other examples are shown in Fig. 2.3.
> [image]

It then says the following:

> This language consists of strings with a *b*, followed by at least two *a*'s, followed by an exclamation point. The set of operators that allows us to say things like "some number of *a*s" are based on the asterisk or $\ast$, commonly called the **Kleene $\ast$** (generally pronounced "cleany star"). The Kleene star means "zero or more occurrences of the immediately previous character or regular expression". So $\text{/a$\ast$/}$ means "any string of zero or more *a*s". This will match *a* or *aaaaaa*, but it will also match *Off Minor* since the string *Off Minor* has zero *a*'s. So the regular expression for matching one or more *a* is $\text{/aa$\ast$/}$, meaning one *a* followed by zero or more *a*s. More complex patterns can also be repeated. So $\text{/[ab]$\ast$/}$ means "zero or more *a*'s or *b*'s" (not "zero or more right square braces"). This will match strings like *aaaa* or *ababab* or *bbbb*.
> For specifying multiple digits (useful for finding prices) we can extend $\text{/[0-9]/}$, the regular expression for a single digit. An integer (a string of digits) is thus $\text{/[0-9][0-9]$\ast$/}$. (Why isn't it just $\text{/[0-9]$\ast$/}$?)

I don't understand why an integer (a string of digits) isn't $\text{/[0-9]$\ast$/}$. For $\text{/[0-9][0-9]$\ast$/}$, it seems to me that, if we go by order of precedence, the first $\text{[0-9]}$ is a single digit, and then $\text{[0-9]$\ast$}$ is the next zero or more occurrences of digits, so this part makes sense. But it seems to me that $\text{/[0-9]$\ast$/}$ would just be the next zero or more occurrences of digits, so it seems that that would work as well, no? What am I misunderstanding here for $\text{/[0-9][0-9]$\ast$/}$ and $\text{/[0-9]$\ast$/}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty word $\epsilon$ isn't an integer. Integers are $0, 1, 2, 3, \dots, 10, 11, \dots$

Clearly none of them have $0$ letters when you write them, and hence they are not $\epsilon$.

Hence, you want an integer to be of the form $\text{/[0-9][0-9]$^\ast$/}$.

Comment: What do you mean by “empty word $\epsilon$”?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is denoted to express the word without any letters in it. Literally. if you write $a\epsilon$ it becomes just $a$. Take a look at this wikipedia page, it might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string

Answer (score 2):

$[0-9]*$ includes all finite strings of the digits including the empty string $\epsilon$ (Some books denote the empty string by $\lambda$). An integer, by definition, has at least one digit. Hence, $[0-9][0-9]*$ is the correct definition. It is not possible to obtain an empty string from this definition.